# Refused to apply style from 'xxx/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, mime

I am new to [Google App Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine) and I'm trying to get the project I've been running locally hosted there.

My *index.html* file shows up, but it is not applying the CSS to it.  I'm not exactly sure what a [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) type is, and I'm not exactly sure where in my code it's trying to get this from.  I just assumed that it would just load the tag that I have in my HTML content and apply it like how it did while using browsersync. File *index.html* is loaded via:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});
```

CSS being loaded in file *index.html*:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Comment: Could you show your some html where you load css ?

Comment: edited original post

Comment: You do not need the type attribute in link. And also close the link tag with /> at the end. Even if not necessary in html but it is in xhtml.

Comment: Also be sure that css file contains no html tag

Comment: It looks like no matter what file you request, including style.css, your server is going to serve index.html. Since that's an html file, not a css one, the browser is rejecting it with the error in your title.

Answer (score 0):

Permanent fix:

File *server.js*

```
app.use(express.static('./public'));
```

And move all your static resources to a public directory in your project. Then your HTML content is valid.

[Source](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you're returning the stylesheet from the server, you should set the content-type attribute for the header to `text/css` i.e. you should have something like

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

app.get('/style', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/css');
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/style.css'));
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue could probably be with the *CSS library* starting with comments.

In development, if the style sheet is started with some comments, it could be seen as something different from CSS.

Removing the library and putting it into a vendor file, may solve the issue.

Another possibility for [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) applications is that you should check your configuration.

Example:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + ‘/public’));
```

Notice that */public* does not have a forward slash at the end, so you will need to include it in your *href* option of your HTML:

Example:

```
href=”/css/style.css”>
```

If you did include a forward slash `/public/`, then you can just do `href=”css/style.css”>.`

Be sure that the CSS name is *style.css* without the second "s" at the end. That could also cause the issue.